# Why is my <footer></footer> not appearing in PHP using include function?

Tags: php, html, include

I have been using this index.php format:

```
<?php

//this is to include the header
require 'includes/header.php';
//this is to include the content menu
    include 'includes/content.php';
?>

<?php
    //this is to include the footer
    include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

And the server does not seem to catch the includes/footer.php file as when I go to developer tools it shows the following without the footer tag:

[image]

And this is my footer.php file:

```
<footer class="website-footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="logo">Whit<span>BLOG</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">Copyright &copy; Made with love by Jason &#9829; </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                    <div class="footer-content">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Anyone may have an idea of what is the issue?

Comment: Open source code and see if footer code is there.

Comment: It is not there!

Comment: Try to `require 'footer.php'` - if something is incorrect with file, you'll get the fatal error.